# TypeError: 'UploadedFile' object is not subscriptable in Streamlit

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series, streamlit, facebook-prophet

I have created a forecasting `ML model` using `Prophet library`. Unfortunately, Prophet only takes `ds` and `y` named axis. That's why, I came up with a code to rename the axis of any Time-series dataset. But, when I deploy my model using `Streamlit` the code returns the following stated error.

```
TypeError: 'UploadedFile' object is not subscriptable
```

Libraries:

```
import streamlit as st
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from prophet import Prophet
from prophet.diagnostics import performance_metrics
from prophet.diagnostics import cross_validation
from prophet.plot import plot_cross_validation_metric
import base64
```

Here's my entire code

```
st.info(f"Upload a .csv file first")

if df is not None:
    df.columns = ['ds', 'y']
    df['ds'] = pd.to_datetime(df['ds'])
    data = pd.read_csv(df)
    
    st.write(data)
    max_date = data['ds'].max()
```

A Gimplse of how my CSV file looks

```
Datetime,AEP_MW
2004-12-31 01:00:00,13478.0
2004-12-31 02:00:00,12865.0
2004-12-31 03:00:00,12577.0
2004-12-31 04:00:00,12517.0
2004-12-31 05:00:00,12670.0
```

Comment: Where is user input for **upload file**?

Comment: That's was in another part of the code. I just uploaded the code where the error was happening. Because the statement looks totally fine. I suspect it has something to do with Streamlit

Comment: I think it has something to do with the uploaded file. Maybe is not actually a well formatted CSV, What I mean is that, maybe the format of the CSV file is not agreeing with your operations.

Comment: **Note:** If no body knows what your CSV file contains it then becomes hard to reproduce the error. So you can edit your question to add a **demo** of your CSV file and some more code.

Comment: I've uploaded a portion of my csv file

Comment: Looking at your code, I think what you want to do is to `display` the CSV file in `pandas dataframe` and also to  get the `max` of  `AEP_MW` e.g: `max_date` as `2004-12-31 01:00:00,13478.0`. Is that right?

Comment: Without the st.file_uploader part of your code will be hard to help you.

Comment: Rafael! What I could understand is Streamlit isn't able to process the column rewriting procedure that I wrote to make it usable for propeht library. I had tried to convert the csv file into an array using numpy but returns bunch of new errors. I believe It could be a bug in Streamlit. As I have seen the same problem occuring in another GitHub project while trying find for a solution.